# Shared cache content in load balanced nginx proxy

Tags: nginx

```
                       <---> NGX CACHE - NODE A \
REQUESTS <---> LB <-->                           <----> SHARED FS (NAS)
                       <---> NGX CACHE - NODE B /
```

I'm trying to accomplish something like this, requests are load balanced among several nodes which should serve shared cached content when available.
We're experiencing random MISS results, even though the content was stored in the cache filesystem by one of the other nodes. What we can see from logs is that sometimes node A identifies as HIT content cached by node B but sometimes it doesn't.

According to the documentation https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/, the mandatory keys_zone parameter sets up a shared memory zone for storing the cache keys and metadata to quickly determine if a request is a HIT or a MISS without having to go to disk.

This is the relevant part of our configuration:

```
            proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
             :           :            :
            location ~* ^/api/rdPage.aspx {
                    resolver 10.0.0.1;
                    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
                    proxy_cache_key "$proxy_host$uri$request_body";
                    proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
                    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
                    proxy_cache_methods POST;
                    proxy_cache_min_uses 0;
                    proxy_cache my_zone;

                    # WITH PROXY LB SERVER
                    proxy_pass http://api-server/rdPage.aspx$is_args$args;
                    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
                    proxy_connect_timeout   15;
                    proxy_send_timeout        15;
                    proxy_read_timeout        1800;
            }
```

How does the keys_zone "shared" memory zone work for several nodes? If it's in memory, how can it be shared? Any alternatives w/o adding custom modules such as SR Cache to nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/sr_cache/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx can not share disk-based cache between nodes. Placing cache on shared disk is a bad idea too, it's a bad design. Any network troubles with shared disk, any high latency due network delay and distribution lock accruing can dramatically decrease nginx performance.

Leave cache on local disk. If you are use multiple nodes as load balancing - you can use cache sharding. Each node will receive part of requests and cache it. If you target is HA, each nodes shoud keep own full cache.

More info about all this cases you can read on nginx site: https://www.nginx.com/blog/shared-caches-nginx-plus-cache-clusters-part-1/ about sharding and https://www.nginx.com/blog/shared-caches-nginx-plus-cache-clusters-part-2/ about HA.